# Symbols in Math Mode

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I am trying to put the following into LaTeX, using math mode.

```
  $ \urcorner \box (Alarm = On \wedge DoorControls = Enabled) $
```

This is an LTL statement, when I inserted the above everything is printed except for the \box. I also get the following error message.

```
Missing $ inserted
Leading text: $ \urcorner
Missing number, treated as zero
Leading text: $ \urcorner \box (
```

Can somebody please help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: `\box` is a primitive command, with a very different purpose; perhaps you are meaning `$\urcorner\mbox{(Alarm...)}$`

Comment: This line doesn't seem to work either, as it doesn't show any of the symbols.

Comment: What symbols do you need? Please add a description of the intended result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
$ \lnot \square \mbox{Alarm} = \mbox{On} \wedge \mbox{DoorControls} = \mbox{Enabled}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't show the box. I was already using the ams package.

Comment: @mitchnufc The symbol for the logical not is rather `\lnot` than `\urcorner`. The meaning of `\box` is not clear to me. The parentheses are missing.